# Reading in an R list for a constructor throws error: expecting a single value

Tags: c++, r, rcpp

I am compiling a package with Rcpp/RcppArmadillo and am getting an error which I believe is from the Rcpp as.h header. I have a constructor written which takes in a list from R and creates the appropriate class. The function calling the constructor and the actual constructor are shown below. I am trying to follow the code shown here (http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Rcpp.html) on lists and data frames.

```
#include "varInf.h"

//[[Rcpp::depends(RcppArmadillo)]]
//[[Rcpp::export]]
void varInfInput(Rcpp::List model_r)
{
    mm_model model = mm_model(model_r);
    varInfC(model);
}
```

This is the constructor mm_model.h which is included in varInf.h

```
using namespace Rcpp ;
using namespace arma;
class mm_model
{
public:
int T ;
int J ;
IntegerVector Rj ;
int maxR ;
IntegerVector Nijr ;
int maxN ;
int K ;
IntegerVector Vj ;
int maxV ;
NumericVector alpha;
NumericVector theta;
IntegerVector Z ;
NumericVector lambda ;
NumericVector phi ;
NumericVector delta ;
NumericVector obs ;
int dist;

mm_model(List model)
{
    T = (int) model[0];
    J = (int) model[1];
    Rj = as<IntegerVector>(model[2]);
    maxR = max(Rj);
    Nijr = as<IntegerVector>(model[3]);
    maxN = max(Nijr);
    K = (int) model[4];
    Vj = as<IntegerVector>(model[5]);
    maxV = max(Vj);
    alpha = as<NumericVector>(model[6]);
    theta = as<NumericVector>(model[7]);
    Z = as<IntegerVector>(model[8]);
    lambda = as<NumericVector>(model[9]);
    phi = as<NumericVector>(model[10]);
    delta = as<NumericVector>(model[11]);
    obs = as<NumericVector>(model[12]);
    dist = (int) model[13];
}
}
```

When I call (the autogenerated wrapper for) varInfInput from R though, it throws the following error.

```
Error: expecting a single value 
3 stop(structure(list(message = "expecting a single value", call = NULL, 
cppstack = NULL), .Names = c("message", "call", "cppstack"
), class = c("Rcpp::not_compatible", "C++Error", "error", "condition"
))) 
2 varInfInput(output) at varInfFit.R#14
1 mmVarFit(test_model)
```

I'm pretty new and have been trying to read up as much as possible, so even a reference to something that might help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I think I fixed my own problem. When I read in the int's, they are being read in as SEXP objects still and I can't just typecast them to int. When I use T = as<IntegerVector>(model[0])[0]; it seems to work as expected.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think I fixed my own problem. When I read in the int's, they are being read in as SEXP objects still and I can't just typecast them to int. When I use

```
T = as<IntegerVector>(model[0])[0];
```

it seems to work as expected